# Haskell double array pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I have a these datatypes

```
data RGB = RGB Int Int Int 

data Grid a = G [[a]]
```

and a function

```
returnFirstRed :: Grid RGB -> Int
```

So basically, the function returns the first color value from a double array of RGB values.

A grid RGB looks like

```
 G[[RGB 50, 50, 50, RGB 100,200, 200],
   [RGB, 75,75,75, RGB 80,80,80]]
```

So for this grid, I would want to return 50.

My problem is pattern matching and extracting the RGB values out of the Grid.

Doing

```
returnFirstRed (G xs) = (head xs) !! 0
```

results in an RGB Value rather than an int

I've tried a lot of different ways to get the r value but I can't get it to work and I can't find a similar example online anywhere. I'm trying to learn Haskell and pretty lost on what to do here..

Comment: You have too many commas in the sample value: `G [[RGB 50 50 50, RGB 100 200 200], [RGB 75 75 75, RGB 80 80 80]]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can pattern match all the way down without using `head` or `!! 0` (of which `head` is considered much nicer btw). `[1,2,3]` is syntactic sugar for `1:2:3:[]` (try it in `ghci`) so you can match the head of the list with `x:rest` and if you don't need the rest, just `x:_`.

But what do you return for `returnFirstRed (G [[]])`, i.e. if the input list is empty? I'd propose returning a `Maybe` instead, so you can return `Nothing` for the input of the empty list.

```
returnFirstRed :: Grid RGB -> Maybe Int
returnFirstRed (G (((RGB r _ _):_):_)) = Just r
returnFirstRed _ = Nothing
```

Comment: `head` is not quite as bad as `!!0`, but it should still be avoided.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```
returnFirstRed (G ((RGB x _ _):_):_)) = x
```

Notice that the x is the first element inside the RGB, which is the head of a list, which is the head of another list, which is the only element inside the G.

You could, of course, NOT use pattern matching at all, or use some pattern matching, or any intermediate between those. An example of that in practice would be:

```
returnFirstRed (G x) = extractFromRGB $ head $ head x
  where extractFromRGB (RGB y _ _) = y
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked great!

Answer (score 2):

The smallest change to make to get your code working is to pattern match on the extracted `RGB` value.

```
returnFirstRed (G xs) = let RGB x _ _ = (head xs) !! 0 in x
```

Note that `head xs` is the same as `xs !! 0`, if you want to write that more uniformly:

```
returnFirstRed (G xs) = let RGB x _ _ = xs !! 0 !! 0 in x
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

define your accessor methods

```
red,green,blue :: RGB -> Int
red (RGB r _ _) = r
green (RGB _ g _) = g
blue (RGB _ _ b) = b

first :: Grid a -> [a]
first (G as) = head as
```

now you can write

```
> grid = G [[RGB 50 50 50, RGB 100 200 200], [RGB 75 75 75, RGB 80 80 80]]

> red $ head $ first grid
50
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!